# sbt: how to add fastOptJS to stage

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, sbt-native-packager

I have cross-project (JVM + JS) and also use sbt native packager. With clean JVM projects I have found handy to use `~stage` command on my development iterations.

The project contains plenty of `main`s, and this style permit to run multiple `main`s with script getting CLASSPATH from prepared stages on the separated terminals.

Now I'd want to add `fastOptJS` command be also executed (inserted into, merged with, or what?) on the `~stage` triggering cycle.

How to?

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a dependency.

```
stage := (stage dependsOn fullOptJs).value
```

This should execute fullOptJs for every stage call.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, in fact it is very simple - just use

```
 ~ ;fastOptJS ;stage
```

in sbt session.